# Create Table from Another Table - MYSQL to MSSQL conversion

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm in the process of converting a database from MYSQL to MSSQL/TSQL, and I can't get the following MYSQL query to work in MSSQL.  Looking for a fresh set of eyes to see what I'm missing.

**Working MYSQL Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable 
AS (SELECT * FROM Note WHERE createdate IN (SELECT MAX(createdate) 
FROM Note GROUP BY `taskPK`));
```

The query looks for the max date of a note row for a given id.  There may be multiple Note rows with the same ID and it will find the newest row and insert it into the new table.

**Non-Working MSSQL Example 1:**  (Incorrect Syntax near '(')

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable 
AS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Note WHERE createdate IN (SELECT MAX(createdate) 
FROM dbo.Note GROUP BY taskPK));
```

**Non-Working MSSQL Example 2:** (Incorrect Syntax near the keyword INTO)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Note 
WHERE createdate IN (SELECT MAX(createdate) FROM Note GROUP BY taskPK) 
INTO tempTable FROM Note;
```

This new table (once created) will be used in the following query (which I haven't tested yet in MSSQL):

```
SELECT Task.id, Task.taskdescription, Task.status, TaskSchedule.date, TaskGroups.name, tempTable.createDate FROM Task 
LEFT JOIN TaskSchedule ON Task.id = TaskSchedule.taskPK
LEFT JOIN TaskGroups ON Task.taskgroupid = TaskGroups.id
LEFT JOIN tempTable ON Task.id = tempTable.taskPK
WHERE Task.userPK = '$userPK' AND Task.status = 'Open'
ORDER BY tempTable.createDate DESC;
```

The above query selects a task that includes the newest note from the previous query I'm having problems with -- adding this incase I'm making this more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Create table as` or `Select table into` in mssql

Use:

```
SELECT * INTO tempTable FROM Note N
WHERE N.createdate IN (SELECT MAX(N1.createdate) FROM Note N1 GROUP BY N1.taskPK)
```